# How to import chance from chancejs in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, chancejs

I have installed chancejs using the command below:

```
npm install chance
```

I have created an angular 10 project and cannot find any chance.js library added. When I try to use the chance methods such as chance.string() in the file employee.component.spec.ts, it says chance does not exist.

```
  var randomName = **chance**.string();
```

I have checked other tutorials where they are importing the script directly into the html component. But is there another way to import it as a Module in typescript?

Answer (score 1):

First solution:

```
import chance from 'chance';

var randomName = chance().string();
```

Second solution:

in `scripts` under `build`:

```
node_modules/chance/dist/chance.min.js
```

and

```
declare var Chance; // After imports in component/service etc.

var randomName = Chance().string();
```

Comment: The first version is preferable. Also, in the second version, the `declare var Chance` _**does not**_ need to be placed "After imports in component/service etc."

Comment: @AluanHaddad I only meant to not put `declare var Chance` inside `class` but you are right. Why first version is preferable thought?

Comment: Because it is a module, and importing it states the dependency and thereby causes loading/bundling/typechecking, improving maintainability and clarity (if a new version changes the directory structure of the distribution, you don't have to update a thing). Also, global variables are bad. That's why we have module systems and we should use them wherever possible.

Answer (score 0):

install **chance** in your angular project

```
npm i chance
```

and then import **chance.min.js** in your **angular.json** file.

```
"scripts": ["node_modules/chance/dist/chance.min.js"]
```

and then in your component declare chance in import section like this.

```
declare var Chance: any;
```

and in your class

```
export class component implements OnInit {
chance: any;
constructor() {
    this.chance = new Chance();
    console.log(this.chance.ip());
  }
}
```

after all these steps please restart your dev server. hope it will work.
happy coding :)

Comment: It's a module, why would you load it as a script?

Comment: @AluanHaddad thanks for the clarification. i just read your comment in which u explained in detail about why we should use module import. i will update my answer as well. thanks